# No space to recreate index after dropping

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, database-design

I had an index on a specific column - I decided to drop that index, but later on wanted to re-add it (the database was still the same size at this point).

When I try to re-add it, I find that my disk no longer has the space to do so. My question at this point is - how could it have been possible for me to have the disk space for an index, yet not have enough disk space to re-create that same index after dropping it (when the database size remained unchanged)?

Comment: What's hard to understand? You need extra space for temporary data while the index is being created that isn't needed afterward. When a house is being constructed, it needs extra space outside to hold the piles of construction materials that aren't needed once those materials are made part of the house.

Comment: What version are you running?  There have been some improvements in this area.